# Using "if then" statements inside a "for" loop in Microsoft VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull numerical grade values and convert them into a string which will represent the grade, A >90, B >80, and so on. I planned to use a for loop to gather the values from the spreadsheet and then if then statements to assign the letter designation. Here is the code I have so far.

```
 For i = 1 To 11
' Pull Grade numerical value
    Grade = Cells(2 + i, 16).Value
' Assign Numerical Value a script Grade
    If Grade > 60 Then
        Letter = "D"
    If Grade > 70 Then
        Letter = "C"
    If Grade > 80 Then
        Letter = "B"
    If Grade > 90 Then
        Letter = "A"
    Else
        Letter = "F"
    Exit
' Print the letter grade
    Cells(2 + i, 17).Text = Letter
    Next i
```

I keep getting errors either pertaining to "Exit" or to "Next i". I have tried using "End" statements as well but that didn't fix the problems either.

Comment: You can do this with a formula. Do you need VBA?

Comment: You have to close off the `IF` block  with `END IF`

Comment: I would reverse the order, too, with the criteria for an "A" on top. Otherwise you might stop short and give everyone a "D" without the chance to see if they earned a higher grade. This is only necessary if you decide to use `Else Ifs`.

Comment: This URL explains why to use "End If": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement

Comment: When you get the syntax for the If, elseif, else,end if correct you will find that your code only assigns a D or an F.  This is because the If , then ,elseif stops at the first satisfied condition, so because an A is > 90 it is also greater than 60,therefore >90 satisfies the first condition , which is > 60, therefore >90 will be allocated a D.  I'm not sure if this will make you popular with your students!!.  This is why a previous commenter suggested to put the a grading first i.e. test for A, B, C, D then F because  >90 is greater than 80-89 etc.

Answer (score 7):

Or just use a formula in column Q:

```
=IF(P:P>=90,"A",IF(P:P>=80,"B",IF(P:P>=70,"C",IF(P:P>=60,"D","F"))))
```

so it updates automatically and you don't need to use VBA.

---

Alternatively you can add a sheet named `GradeList` with the following data

[image]

and use

```
=INDEX(GradeList!B:B,MATCH(P:P,GradeList!A:A,1))
```

as formula. This way you can easily edit the numbers/grades later, and it will pick the correct grades automatically:

[image]

Comment: I normally would've done that as I've used this technique in the past. My professor required me to use a button and VBA to do the work this time.

Comment: Nice :) @AustinG you can use VBA to enter this formula in all that range in one go. `rng.Formula = Above formula` and then `rng.Value = rng.Value`. Just two lines of code...

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer *Select Case* in this situation. And start the Loop from 3 so you don't need to add 2:

```
For i = 3 To 11
  ' Pull Grade numerical value
  Grade = Cells(i, 16).Value
  ' Assign Numerical Value a script Grade
  Select Case Grade
    Case Is >= 90: letter = "A"
    Case Is >= 80: letter = "B"
    Case Is >= 70: letter = "C"
    Case Is >= 60: letter = "D"
    Case Else: letter = "F"
  End Select
  ' Print the letter grade
  Cells(i, 17).Value = letter
 Next i
```

Comment: Great answer, but you have fallen for the same pitfall as OP as pointed out by Matt Creemens. It is important you start with the highest number first, or the first condition will resolve as TRUE for everything above 60, and they will all get a "D".

Comment: @Plutian Argh, you're right. I've edited it. In Java, you need a break for every case. Otherwise, the next case is checked, too. In VBA it's different, I hadn't thought of that :-)

Comment: Yeah, VBA is much lazier than that. If it encounters a `True` it will immediately end the select case and be happily on its way.

Answer (score 5):

Great answers from everyone, but surprised not to see a `Select...Case` mentioned here. This is a perfect example, perhaps even textbook.

`Select...Case` evaluates a variable according to a number of criteria and then does whatever is written inside the case statement.

So your code would look like this:

```vb
For i = 3 To 13
' Pull Grade numerical value
    Grade = Worksheets("YourSheetNameHere").Cells(i, 16).Value 'Change that sheet name
    'do our evaluation based on "grade"
    Select Case Grade
        Case >= 90
            Letter = "A"
        Case >= 80
            Letter = "B"
        Case >= 70
            Letter = "C"
        Case >= 60
            Letter = "D"
        Case Else
            Letter = "F"
    End Select

Next i
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a bunch of problems here.

First `exit` needs to be `end if`

Second You need `elseif` for multiple conditions in the same if statement.

Lastly you need to reorder your ifs. If you have a grade of 90 it would return a "D" as that is the first true statement it encounters.

You might as well just loop from 3 - 13 instead of adding 2 each time aswell. And make sure you use explicit references, it will eventually bite you.

I missed one thing, Make all your comparisons `>=` Folks won't be happy if their 90 is a B.

```
For i = 3 To 13
' Pull Grade numerical value
    Grade = Worksheets("YourSheetNameHere").Cells(i, 16).Value 'Change that sheet name
' Assign Numerical Value a script Grade
    If Grade >= 90 Then
        Letter = "A"
    elseIf Grade >= 80 Then
        Letter = "B"
    elseIf Grade >= 70 Then
        Letter = "C"
    elseIf Grade >= 60 Then
        Letter = "D"
    Else
        Letter = "F"
    End if
' Print the letter grade
    Worksheets("YourSheetNameHere").Cells(i, 17).value = Letter 'Change that sheet name
    Next i
```

Comment: Ive tried a few of the changes you suggested, I didnt add Worksheets() in yet. I am still getting an error about the Next i line, "Next without for" is the error message.

Comment: Did you change the ```ifs``` (aside from the first) to ```elseifs``` and did you change ```exit``` to ```end if```?

Comment: @AustinG make sure you have `Then` at the end of every line except for the `Else` line. That error text is often thrown when dropping a `Then`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use `INDEX` and `MATCH` as `Application.Function`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Grade As Long: Grade = 55
Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "F")
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array(100, 89, 79, 69, 59)

With Application
    Debug.Print .Index(arr1, .Match(Grade, arr2, -1))
End With

End Sub
```

Or drop the `INDEX` function, and call the array directly:

```
With Application
    Debug.Print arr1(.Match(Grade, arr2, -1) - 1)
End With
```

Obviously implement this in your loop/function and write the returned value to your cells. Change `Grade` variable to see the different values this would return =)

Comment: Another nice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format of the code to match Jclasley and it works fine, here is my final code:

```
For i = 1 To 11
' Pull Grade numerical value
    Grade = Cells(2 + i, 16).Value
' Assign Numerical Value a script Grade
    Select Case Grade
        Case Is >= 90
            Letter = "A"
        Case Is >= 80
            Letter = "B"
        Case Is >= 70
            Letter = "C"
        Case Is >= 60
            Letter = "D"
        Case Else
            Letter = "F"
    End Select
    Cells(2 + i, 17).Value = Letter
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the best answer.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer which was most useful to you as accepted (grey tick next to the answer) [to show your appreciation for their hard work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).